# C++ code with ADO is not running on another PC

Tags: c++, ado

I made a simple c++ code using ADO, which reads and writes Excel data to c++.

I finished and confirmed running the code in my 1st PC, and I have to move it to another PC.

However, moved code is not working, despite I moved all project folders/files and msado15.dll.

In details, it has the problem when opening the excel file, where

```
inline HRESULT Recordset15::Open ( const _variant_t & Source, const _variant_t & ActiveConnection, enum CursorTypeEnum CursorType, enum LockTypeEnum LockType, long Options ) {

    HRESULT _hr = raw_Open(Source, ActiveConnection, CursorType, LockType, Options);

    if (FAILED(_hr)) _com_issue_errorex(_hr, this, __uuidof(this));
    return _hr;

}
```

and gives me,

> "Microsoft c++ exception: _com error at memory location ~~~" error.

Could you guys give me the answer what's going on?

thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide the value of `_hr`? Can you please provide a [mcve]!?

Comment: It is common that some undefined behaviors manifest themselves as crashes only on some computers and with particular data. If the crash is reliable then it is easy to for you to debug it, but we can't know what in your code causes it.